# jQuery UI : Draggable element is moving inside the sidebar. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have to make a sidebar which has divs inside it and the divs are Draggable and Droppable to the drop area.

**So what I have done:**

I have make a sidebar.

```
$(".draggable").each(function() {
    $(this).draggable({
      zIndex: 999,
      scroll: false,
      revert: 'invalid',
      refreshPosition: true,
    });
});

$(".droppable").droppable({
        accept: '',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            console.log('Function working successfully');
        }

    })
```

Here it is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MyTests/9gwLqpkh/1/)

**Problem:**

My problem is that when I drag the element the dragged element does not go outside the sidebar. Why is it happening and how can I resolve this problem.

Update :

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MyTests/9gwLqpkh/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written overflow: hidden to your sidebar. If you remove that, it will work just fine.

```
.class_sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    /* z-index: 1; */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #E6E9EC;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

The overflow property specifies what happens if content overflows an element's box. This property specifies whether to clip content or to add scrollbars when an element's content is too big to fit in a specified area.

It needs to be removed for the required action to happen.

Comment: but I am also using the perfect-scrollbar

Comment: on which block? The sidebar?

Comment: yes! sidebar actually I have not given you a full code but in fiddle example that I have provided is the exact thing what I need.

Comment: here.. found this online : https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxDataView/samples/05_drag-n-drop/07_auto_scroll.html

Comment: The problem is solved Thanks. Just want to know one this how can I increase my z-index of my divs on drop

Comment: nothing will happen if you change the z-index. The element is getting hidden. There is no other way to show it. You will probably need to create the scroll using jquery.

Comment: Well Thanks for your support.